# Awk to make in place file changes without erasing everything else in file

Tags: bash, awk

I'm using the following code to modify the contents of a file.

```
awk '$1 ~ /command/ { s = ""; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print $1 " " "text I am inserting after command" " " s }' file
```

I have found out that this command alone outputs (to the screen) only the changes to the file which I have told it to make.

I have tried a modification of the command to write the changes back into the file.

```
awk '$1 ~ /command/ { s = ""; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print $1 " " "text I am inserting after command" " " s }' file  > tmp && mv tmp file.
```

However this has the unwanted side effect of erasing everything else in the file that awk was not told to work on. How can I use awk to make these changes, output the changes and input back into the file without erasing everything else in the file that I need? Am I using the right solution for this or do I need to try another approach?

Note: I am on an older version of awk which does not support inplace mods and we can't easily update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just move the `print` to outside of the `<condition> { <action> }` block so it's executed unconditionally Try this:

```
awk '$1 ~ /command/ { s = ""; for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; $0 = $1 " text I am inserting after command " s } 1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

I don't understand what you are trying to do with that loop as it doesn't make sense so I just left it alone. If you post some concise, testable, sample input and expected output you'll get help with that too.

I had a flash of inspiration, this **MAY** be what you are trying to do:

```
awk '$1 ~ /command/ { $1 = $1 " text I am inserting after command" } 1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

If not edit your question to include input/output.